# Change path or refinement

Tags: rebol, red

I want to change the `a/b` inside a block to `a/c` (or possibly even `a`)

The normal way I'd do this is with `change`:

```
test: [a/b]
change test/1 'c
```

but it only changes the first part, i.e. `a` to `c`:

```
>> test
== [c/b]
```

Can't access the path with `test/2` either:

```
>> reduce [test/1 test/2]
== [a/b none]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to note here:

First, `path!` is a series, so in this case, a nested series. Have to actually access the *second* element **inside** the *first* element:

```
>> test: [a/b] test/1/2
== b
```

Secondly, use the property of series that make them behave like pointers and access the `next` element, *instead of accessing it directly*:

```
>> next test/1
== b
```

So the code becomes:

```
>> change next test/1 'c test
== [a/c]
```

Comment: An alternative shorter way using path access only would be: `test/1/2: 'c`