# Change file paths

Tags: rebol, red

I want to change `[%a/b]` to `[%a/c]`.
Basically, the same as [Change path or refinement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696779/change-path-or-refinement), but with `file!` instead:

> I want to change the `a/b` inside a block to `a/c`

```
test: [a/b]
```

In this case, either `change next test/1 'c` or `test/1/2: 'c` works.
But not when `test` is a `file!`:

```
>> test: [%a/b]
== [%a/b]
>> test/1
== %a/b
>> test/1/2         ; can't access 2nd value
== %a/b/2
>> next first test  ; not quite what you expect
== %/b
```

Trying to `change` it gives not something you'd expect:

```
>> change next test/1 'c
== %b
>> test
== [%acb]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing `path!` and `file!` series, they can look similar, but their nature are very different.

A `path!` is a collection of values (often `word!` values) separated by a slash symbol, a `file!` is a collection of `char!` values. Slash characters in `file!` series are just characters, so `file!` has no knowledge about any sub-structures. It has (mostly) the semantics of `string!` series, while `path!` has the semantics of a `block!` series.

Now that this is cleared, about the `test/1/2` result, **path notation on a `file!` series has a different behavior than on `string!`**, it will do a smart *concatenation* instead of acting as an accessor. It's called *smart* because it will nicely handle extra slash characters present in left and right parts. For example:

```
>> file: %/index.html
== %/index.html

>> path: %www/
== %www/

>> path/file
== %www/file

>> path/:file
== %www/index.html
```

Same path notation rule applies to `url!` series too:

```
>> url: http://red-lang.org
== http://red-lang.org

>> url/index.html
== http://red-lang.org/index.html

>> file: %/index.html
== %/index.html

>> url/:file
== http://red-lang.org/index.html
```

So for changing the nested content of `test: [%a/b]`, as `file!` behaves basically as `string!`, you can use any available method for strings to modify it. For example:

```
>> test: [%a/b]
== [%a/b]

>> change skip test/1 2 %c
== %""

>> test
== [%a/c]

>> change next find test/1 slash "d"
== %""

>> test
== [%a/d]

>> parse test/1 [thru slash change skip "e"]
== true

>> test
== [%a/e]
```

Comment: `parse test/1 [thru slash change to end "e"]` was what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Files are string types and can be manipulated in the same way you'd modify a string. For example:

```
test: [%a/b]
replace test/1 %/b %/c
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because file! is an any-string!, not any-array!

```
>> any-string? %a/c
== true
>> any-array? 'a/c
== true
```

So the directory separator '/' in a file! doesn't mean anything special with the action CHANGE. So 'a', '/', and 'b' in %a/b are treated the same way, and the interpreter isn't trying to parse it into a two segment file path [a b].

While for a path!, because it's an array, each component is a rebol value, and the interpreter knows that. For instance, 'bcd' in a/bcd will be seen as a whole (a word!), instead of three characters 'b', 'c' and 'd'.

I agree that the file! being an any-string! is not convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a maybe cumbersome solution, but suitable for directories treating them as files

```
test/1:  to-file head change skip split-path test/1 1 %c
```