# Change word to path

Tags: rebol, red

Yet another question related to [Change path or refinement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696779/change-path-or-refinement)

This time, I want to change the **`a`** inside a block to **`a/b`**

Using `change`:

```
test: [a]
change test 'a/b
```

Splits the values into *two*:

```
>> test
== [a b]
```

Which isn't what I want, but rather, as a *single path* `[a/b]`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `change/only`:

```
test: [a]
change/only test 'a/b
```

Gives:

```
>> test
== [a/b]
```

Answer (score 1):

`change/only` works, though there is a simpler way in that case:

```
>> test: [a]
== [a]

>> test/1: 'a/b
== a/b

>> test
== [a/b]
```